# How to create a Single Entry JS File for VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have a project in Vue that is going to be big, so we are splitting the code in chunks with Webpack configuration, but when I build the project with `vue-cli-service`, it generates an `index.html` that prefetches/preloads all the chunks. I don't want to use this `index.html`. I need a single entry file for Vue that will start the app and import the other files as requested.

I tried `splitChunks: false` in Webpack, but it didn't help:

```js
configureWebpack: {
   optimization: {
     splitChunks: false
   }
}
```

Tried removing the other imports and keeping only the `app.js`, but that also didn't help.

We are using `import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ './views/Login.vue')`, but not in all components.

I previously had another Vue project that worked the way I want: only an `app.js` and a `vendor.js` that import other chunks as needed. Back then, I wasn't using `vue-cli-service`; rather just a simple Webpack config and `System.import( /* webpackChunkName: "Login" */ '@/components/pages/login/Login.vue')` in all components that import the route files:

```html
<html>
...
    <body>
        <div id=app></div>
        <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.2f58f4045cb046ff1dac.js>
        </script>
        <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.877179012e83c1c97b77.js>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to build my project and have a single JS file that I can import in another HTML file, and it will act as a starter file.

Do I just need the `System.import` in all imports? Any other configurations with `vue-cli-service`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preload and prefetch scripts that are inserted into `index.html` (by [`@vue/preload-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/preload-webpack-plugin)) can be disabled via [`chainWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced), yielding only one JavaScript import of `app.js` in `index.html`:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.delete('splitChunks') // no vendor chunks
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')         // no prefetch chunks
    config.plugins.delete('preload')          // no preload chunks
  }
}
```